# 3D views are not visibles in the viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have revit file. I've convert it in svf format with this argument :

`"formats": [
            {
              "type": "svf",
              "views": [
                "2d",
                "3d"
              ]
            }
          ]`

When I load my document in a viewer, I only see 1 3D view instead 15 presents in my Revit file :

[image]

In the viewer, I load the views like this :

`Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(doc.getRootItem(), {
      type: 'geometry'
    }, true);`

But I get only one view

Answer (score 0):

There is a "views for A360" (Revit 2016 earlier) and ‘Publish View’ (2017 to present) setting in the Revit file that defines which 3D Views and 2D Sheets get published for viewing in Forge. It's possible that you need to enable the 3D Views you want.

Here is a link for the instructions you need to do on the Revit side for those views to become available from the Viewer:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Revit-CAR/files/GUID-09FBF9E2-6ECF-447D-8FA8-12AB16495BC3-htm.html

Comment: Kind remind: The ‘View for A360’ has been renamed to ‘Publish View’ since Revit 2017 and higher. :)